# Transpose CSV into DF Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

**I have a JSON that looks like this:**

```
{ID:{"ATT1": "VAL", "ATT2": "VAL","ATT3": "VAL",...}}
```

This JSON has around 3000+ ID's inside of it, all with its own dict of ATT/VAL pairs.

**After I read that I used this:**

```
with open("result.json", "r") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in data.items() ]))

df.to_csv("pandarised.csv", index=False)
```

**Which then gives me a csv like this:**

```
ID
{"ATT": "some att", "VAL": "some val"}
{"ATT": "some att", "VAL": "some val"}
{"ATT": "some att", "VAL": "some val"}
{"ATT": "some att", "VAL": "some val"}
{"ATT": "some att", "VAL": "some val"}
{"ATT": "some att", "VAL": "some val"}
```

There are about 3000 columns, where each column has a new ID and its own set of ATT/VAL dicts. I was trying to read this from DF into Pandas as a new DF, and was trying to make it look like this:

```
   ATT ATT2 ATT3 etc..
ID VAL VAL  VAL  etc..
ID VAL VAL  VAL  etc..
ID VAL VAL  VAL  etc..
ID VAL VAL  VAL  etc..
ID VAL VAL  VAL  etc..
etc..
```

I was thinking to try using either concat with some combination of transpose but I cant seem get a grip on where to start with this.

Thank you

Comment: I think for starters your input JSON is invalid with duplicate keys [edit] I see you edited this

Comment: @tvgriek There are duplicate keys, but not in the same dict for each ID, if that makes sense

Comment: Just realized what you mean, that was my bad I did not represent the JSON properly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
data = [{"ID":{"ATT": "VAL", "ATT2": "VAL"}},
        {"ID":{"ATT": "VAL", "ATT2": "VAL"}}]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for row in data:
    df = df.append(row[list(row.keys())[0]], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Tried it but I get an error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: make sure above example works standalone - looks like your data is not a dict in above format yet

Comment: Ok that is great! One thing I noticed is that it only does 1 row, is there a way to expand that out?

Comment: It will loop over all rows

Comment: Ok I think I solved it, I was not paying attention to the structure of my input there, so it appears to work now. Thank you!